# Which driver to install for touchpad anti-palm detection?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, touchpad

I have an Acer Aspire 5742Z with the factory touchpad installed. Which additional driver do I need to install in order to gain the anti-palm detection (*PalmCheck™*) feature? At the moment, my only option when I want to type without jumping the cursor around, seems to be to manually disable the touchpad by using the key combination `Fn` + `F7`. This shows an icon of a touchpad, with a 'no' sign.

I did find [this](http://www.techspot.com/drivers/driver/file/information/8293/) driver but I'm worried it might be incompatible and break the touchpad! Is this possible? If so, is the driver I linked compatible with the touchpad on the 5742Z?

Comment: An incompatible  driver isn't going to break your touchpad it just would result in your touchpad not working until you supplied it a working driver.  Acer's website has the driver that enables that feature.  You can find it on the driver website which contains the other drivers for the Acer Aspire 5742Z

Comment: @Ramhound Does Acer's driver include PalmCheck?

Comment: It's the only driver that would.  You might also be overestimating the capability of the feature.  Of course might be easier just to go to the Synaptics website and download the current Synaptics driver.  Why are you asking about a Windows XP driver if your running Windows 7?  Furthermore....If you have a Synaptic Touchpad just install the [current driver](http://www.synaptics.com/en/drivers.php)...

Comment: The driver I found for your device, which I assume has a Synaptic Touchpad since your asking about Synaptic device drivers, was `Touchpad Driver 14.0.19.0` and was 29MB.  I found it by search for Aspire 5742,  You should self-answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acer's own driver included the correct components. You can find it [here](http://global-download.acer.com/GDFiles/Driver/TouchPad/TouchPad_Synaptics_14.0.19.0_W7x86W7x64_A.zip?acerid=634176971863216651&Step1=NOTEBOOK&Step2=ASPIRE&Step3=ASPIRE%205742Z&OS=711&LC=en&BC=ACER&SC=EMEA_27).